# How to access property of looped item in view parser?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

The documentation on the view parser [deals with conditions](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/view_parser.html#conditional-logic), but their example deals only with an explicitly defined variables that has no relation with a looped item. Which works for situations like this:

```
{ if $var === 'foo' } 
   <p>This is foo</p>
{ endif }
```

So if I wanted to check the value of a property on a looped item, how would I do that? Ideally, I expect something like this (in this example, `users` is an array):

```
<ul>
  { users }
    <li>{ name }
      { if id == 1 }
        This is the first user
      { endif } 
    </li>
  { /users }
</ul>
```

But, with or without the dollar-sign in front of the `id` in that condition, it complains that the value isn't defined. Perhaps something like `$user['id']` would work, but how can I know the name of the variable that CodeIgniter uses for its inner iterations?

**Edit 1: Data array**

```
$data = [
    'users' => [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'John'
        ], [
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Ben'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: show us your data array

Comment: @AbdullaNilam edited question

Answer (score 0):

Looping is explained in the Docs at [View Fragments.](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/view_parser.html#view-fragments)

You need to combine it with conditional Logic as below:

```
    <ul>
      { users }
        <li>{ name }
          { if $id == 1 }
            This is the first user
          { endif } 
        </li>
      { /users }
    </ul>
```

Comment: Are you saying that this code works for you? (on CodeIgniter 4 RC 3). Because, like I said in my question, it doesn't work for me with or without the dollar sign. Without it it's an "undefined constant", with it it's an "undefined variable".